# Align words in left, but keep one centered

Tags: html, css

I need to put 2 words like this:

```
                               Word1
                               word2 is loneger
```

To align them on left, but second word is centered in div.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I tried to wrap them in div. Issue is that div width is bigger than word 2. So it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the problem is being able to centre a paragraph of text, but keep text within it left-aligned, it could be handled via flexbox CSS:

```css
.centred {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}
```

```html
<div class="centred">
  <p>
    Short<br/>
    Muchlongererererererererer
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you show to us in your post.
Text is aligned to left but in center

```html
<style>
.parent {
 text-align: center;
}

.div {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 150px;
 text-align: left;
}
</style>

<div class="parent">
 <div class="div">Word1</div><br/>
 <div class="div">word2 is loneger<div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood the problem correctly (due to a lack of context) but as `text-align: left` is the default attribute-value, I'd solve this as follows:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>Word1</p>
    <p>Word2 is longer</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div p:last-child {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Problem is this div that wraps those words. It need to wrap longer word somehow.

Comment: Atleast check your [code](https://fiddle.jshell.net/v9vfjsq2/) before posting it.

Comment: Why would I need to check my code? Your fiddle perfectly shows how it's a viable solution to the problem at hand. First line to the left, second line centered.

Comment: If you check @Conan's answer, maybe you'll understand what OP wanted.

Comment: Aaah I see. Obviously I understood the problem as something else. =) Cool.